# RegEx - Add new conditions to existing regex

Tags: regex

I currently have this Regex:

```
.*[a-z]$|.*[A-Z]$|.*[0-9]$
```

I need to add the following to the existing - `/:.#[]()`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Add it in what way? What do you want this regex to do? Provide examples with test data.

Comment: the existing regex is shown, the next line - /:.# these special characters need to be included in the existing one. I'm not sure how more clearly to explain this.

Comment: Your existing regex matches strings ending in a letter or number, are you saying you also want to match when the string ends of any of those characters?

Comment: Actually the condition is the new set to be added, all those special characters should be allowed in a string. I hope that helps. Not ends with or starts with, more like if string contains any of /:.#[]() then its ok

Comment: Contains _any_ of the characters, or _only_ the characters? Should it match against something like `this*string`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple OR conditions. Have only one and include special characters also:

```
[0-9A-Za-z\/#:.()\[\]]
```

Comment: let me try this one. If it works I'll pick this as asnwer. thanks for your help

Comment: Did this work for you? If not just let me know and I will modify add per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comments, this should do it for you:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/:.#\[\]()]+$
```

This will match a string containing only the characters you've specified.

Comment: Isn't this the same regex (except *^* and *+$*) as anubhava's one?

Comment: @ComFreek: The answer provided by anubhava would match against `*this*`, which if I'm interpreting OP's comments correctly, is not what he wants. From the way OP describes it, it seems like he's trying to validate that a string contains _only_ a specific set of characters, not that it contains _any_ of the characters (and possibly others as well).